# How to deal with accents in Scala XML?

Tags: xml, scala, sax

I have this code to load XML from a HTML webpage:

```
import scala.xml._ 
import scala.xml.factory.XMLLoader 
import scala.xml.parsing.NoBindingFactoryAdapter
import org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup.jaxp.SAXFactoryImpl

object XmlUtils {
  def load(s: String) = {
    val adapter = new NoBindingFactoryAdapter
    val factory = (new SAXFactoryImpl())
    val loader = XML.withSAXParser(factory.newSAXParser())
    scala.xml.Utility.trim(loader.loadString(s))   
  }: Node
}
```

The code loads the XML well except for the **&Xaccute;** symbols which are represented as '?' in the terminal output.

I'm new in the Java environment and Scala, so I'm pretty lost.

How can I fix that?

----- more info

I'm using Dispatch to fetch the HTML via HTTP

> url(_url) <:< mapHeaders(headers)

The enviroment which I'm running the program is Akka, and I use the simple `println` to output the data

This is a simple example out of the Akka framework:

```
val s = "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN\"><HTML><HEAD></HEAD><BODY>&aacute;</BODY></HTML>"
val xml = XmlUtils.load(s)
println(xml.text)
```

Output:
`?`

Comment: Show us the XML and how it is read into the String `s`.

Comment: @LutzHorn I use the Dispatch library: 
url(_url) <:< mapHeaders(headers)

Comment: I suspect your problem is displaying things, not reading them, so you should explain how you are displaying them as well, and include the platform you are using.

Comment: Agree with Daniel; I'd check the numeric (Unicode) value of the character.

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral The enviroment which I'm running the program is Akka, and I use the simple println to output the data

Comment: @IvanGuardado That's not the environment. Are you on windows or unix? Are you using a command terminal or graphical output? What's the character set of the terminal, if you are using that? Can it display the character? Is it the same character set that the jvm is using?

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral I'm using the Terminal of MacOSX. If I print the character code I see the 225, which corresponds to `á`. That means that the problem is the output encoding. I don't know how to set the jvm charset...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tweaked your code a little, but it's essentially the same:

```
package scratch

import scala.xml._
import scala.xml.factory.XMLLoader
import scala.xml.parsing.NoBindingFactoryAdapter
import org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup.jaxp.SAXFactoryImpl

object XmlUtils {
  def load(s: String) = {
    val adapter = new NoBindingFactoryAdapter
    val factory = (new SAXFactoryImpl())
    val loader = XML.withSAXParser(factory.newSAXParser())
    val node = scala.xml.Utility.trim(loader.loadString(s))

    node
  }: Node

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val s = "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN\"><HTML><HEAD></HEAD><BODY>&aacute;</BODY></HTML>"
    val xml = XmlUtils.load(s)
    println(xml.text)
  }
}
```

... and changed the "Resource->Text File Encoding" project setting in Eclipse to "UTF-8" and it now produces output like this in a console on OS/X 10.9.1:

```
$ scala -classpath .:../lib/tagsoup-1.2.1.jar scratch.XmlUtils
á
```

I suspect the project setting corresponds to passing the -encoding option to scalac.

Comment: I've added the imports :)

Comment: For future reference the TagSoup library is available here: http://home.ccil.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/

Comment: The Java encoding option was the problem. This works for setting the encoding using sbt: `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS='-Dfile.encoding=UTF8' sbt [...]`